# Arrow up in eclipse git staging

Tags: java, git, eclipse

When I try to make a commit and push, an upwards arrow appears next to the project name. This occurs in eclipse and I do not know how to solve it. I have been waiting for some time and it does not seem to go away. The changes that I have make to the project are not reflected in the repository. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

From the [eGit User Guide](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Inspecting_the_state_of_the_Repository):

```
↑N – The local branch has N commits that are not yet on the
remote-tracking branch. This can be read as "N commits to
push".
```